# Blacklisting ServiceReference

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I am developing a Java application in order to manage event in the OSGi framework. However, I have a warning as following:

```
WARNING: EventAdmin: Blacklisting ServiceReference [[org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler] | Bundle(Scheduler [1])] due to timeout!
```

I know I could solve the problem through the properties of the OSGi server. However, I would like to solve it through code. But, I do not know how I should manage the Event Handler in my Java class in order to avoid this problem. Could any one help me with this issue?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that is reported is quite bad, an event handler is called and does not return.

So the only way out of this is to find out why this handler is not returning from its event method. The object that does not return is identified by the ServiceReference.

Comment: I tend to get this when I'm debugging. If I put a breakpoint in the `EventHandler` then it's pretty much guaranteed that I will bust the timeout (being a big, stupid and slow human!) and get blacklisted. For these scenarios you can disable the timeout through configuration, but it's not recommended to leave it that way in production because `EventHandler`s are really supposed to return immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Peter that you should make sure `EventHandler`s return in reasonable amount of time (e.g. by kicking of additional work in a background thread.)

However, it may be useful to turn off blacklisting sometimes, such as during debugging (as Neil states.)

Judging from the error message, you're using the [Felix Event Admin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-event-admin.html), which responds to both framework properties and to config admin.

- You can set the system property `org.apache.felix.eventadmin.Timeout=0` to disable blacklisting, or
- you can use Configuration Admin to set the same property, using PID `org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.EventAdmin`. If you run with different configurations for debug- and release builds, this may be the way to go.